# Second sibling div element not inheriting the height

Tags: html, css

Trying to change the size of the #Leftbar but if I did it in pixels or percentages it wouldn't change so I tried changing the parent size so I could use percentages. For some reason it works for the first div but not for the sibling

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head class="Setup">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="I don't want to reveal my path but it's accurate">
</head>
<body class="Setup">
    <div class="Design">
        <div class="TopDesign">
            <p id="Topbar"></p>
            <p id="Minibar"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="LeftDesign">
            <span id="Leftbar"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
* {
    margin: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    top: inherit;
    left: inherit;
    font-family: Menlo;
    font-style: italic;
}

html {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#Topbar {
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

#Minibar {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    width: 80%;
    height: 2.5em;
    top: 5em;
    left: 5em;
}

#Leftbar {
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    width: 5em;
    height: 10em;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some hint of what you actually want to happen? Image wise. Crude drawings of boxes would be fine... But I don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/axb19s, http://prntscr.com/axb1fi, and http://prntscr.com/axb1ko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still feel like I'm missing something, but an html element is an empty box. By itself it has no height and no width. Even when you define the height and width it is like having a cardboard box that has no contents and has yet been taped together.

You can fix that by adding `display: block`. This tapes the box together and allows you to see it's contents.

I won't talk anything about the fact you have ems. Those confuse me quite a bit.

```css
* {
    margin: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    top: inherit;
    left: inherit;
    font-family: Menlo;
    font-style: italic;
}

html {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#Topbar {
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

#Minibar {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    width: 80%;
    height: 2.5em;
    top: 5em;
    left: 5em;
}

#Leftbar {
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    width: 5em;
    height: 10em;
    display: block; // ?? is this what you're trying to do??
}
```

```html
<div class="Design">
        <div class="TopDesign">
            <p id="Topbar"></p>
            <p id="Minibar"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="LeftDesign">
            <span id="Leftbar"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `span`s (as `#Leftbar` is) are inline elements. You should use `display:block|inline-block`, `float` or `position:absolute|fixed` in order to be able to set `width` and `height`.

Remember that `em` unit is related to the font size.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, the problem is #Leftbar is a span. A `<span>` is an inline. You can:

1 - Use a `<div>` instead of a span, which is a block type.

2 - Use CSS with an adaptive `display`, for example:

```
display: block;
```

or

```
display: inline-block;
```

Hope it helps